# converting a string into a sequence of strings

Tags: string, list, split, scheme, lisp

I've created piglatin translator which converts words into their piglatin counterparts.

Following the procedure below,

```
(translate '("ark" "gold"))
```

gives

```
"arkway golday"
```

However I want to input simply (translate "ark gold") and get "arkway golday"

I figured i'd use string-split and string-join however I seem to be making a mistake adding:

```
(define (piglatin phrase)
    (string-split translate phrase))
```

and running (piglatin '("ark gold"))

gives me the error:

```
string-split: contract violation
  expected: (or/c string? regexp?)
  given: '("ark gold")
```

code:

```
#lang racket

(define (piglatin phrase)
    (string-split translate phrase))

(define (translate sentence)
  (string-join (map breakSentence sentence)))

; break down sentance string split into a list
(define (breakSentence word)
  (list->string (listWord (string->list word))))

; break down word for vowel testing
(define (listWord word)
  (cond
    ((foundVowel (car word))
     (startsVowel word))
    (else(noVowel word '()))))

; letters that are vowels, their prensence indicates way should be added to end
(define (foundVowel letter)
  (member letter '(#\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y)))

; allow adding way to end of word
(define (startsVowel word)
  (append word '(#\w #\a #\y)))
```

Comment: `string-split` takes as first parameter a string, while you are giving it the function `translate`. Check your parentheses.

Comment: Your translation is incorrect.  It should be "arkway" "oldgay"

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string into words before translating them.

```
(define (piglatin phrase)
  (translate (string-split  phrase)))
```